# Remove highlight (border) from around selected vuetify accordion item

Tags: vuetify.js, accordion

I am using vuetify 3. I would like to remove the highlight/border from around the active accordion item in a v-expansion-panel. The highlight goes away when I click off the item. Is it possible to make the highlight/border "hidden" when accordion is clicked? Thank you in advance for your help.

Please reference image. [Selected accordion item with highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3TR5.jpg)

Here is example code I am using:

```
<v-expansion-panels
          variant="accordion"
          v-model="openedPanel">

            <v-expansion-panel
              :class="toggle || openedPanel === 'acc1' ? 'atom-accordion-active' : 'atom-accordion-inactive'"
              title="Accordion 1"
              value="acc1"
              @click="LoseFocus"
              text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, ratione debitis quis est labore voluptatibus! Eaque cupiditate minima"
            >
            </v-expansion-panel>

            <v-expansion-panel
              :class="toggle || openedPanel === 'acc2' ? 'atom-accordion-active' : 'atom-accordion-inactive'"
              title="Accordion 2"
              value="acc2"
              text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, ratione debitis quis est labore voluptatibus! Eaque cupiditate minima"
            >
            </v-expansion-panel>

        </v-expansion-panels>
```

Comment: I don't think this is default behavior, is it? Can you provide a link where expansion panel behaves like that?

Comment: I am new to vuetify so I am unsure. I added sample code to my initial question.

Comment: Pretty sure it is the `atom-accordion-active` class. What happens, when you remove that?

Answer (score 0):

you can override the css of the accordion like this:

```
.v-expansion-panel--active {
    box-shadow: none; /* Remove box-shadow */
    border: none; /* Remove border */
    /* You can add other styling here as needed */
}
```